# Regular expression not return when match fail?

Tags: regex

In [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fwMtO4/1/):
When i using regular expression `/.*(?!~D)/` in the string `Abc~D`

I think the matching will be failed in the character `'c'`

and return the matching result will be `'Ab'`

But in fact the actual matching result will be the `Abc~D` ,seems that the matching will proceeded after failed in `'c'` .

Comment: You are confused about how lookarounds work.  `(?!~D)` means assert that what follows the immediate position is _not_ `~D`.  So, the regex matches `Ab`, but then stops before `c`.  It cannot match `c`, because then the negative lookahead would fail.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks ,no i got where my problem is , it is because the .* will  match the whole string at first , so there will be no stop in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the pattern `.*` will first match until the end of the string. Then it will assert what is on the right is not `~D`, which is true because it is at the end of the string so it will match the whole string.

You could for example start at the beginning of the string `^` and repeat matching all the characters that are not followed by `~D`

```
^(?:.(?!~D))*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `.(?!~D)` Match any char except a newline and assert what is directly to the right is not `~D`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0 or more times

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R368Cu/1)

If you want to take whitespace boundaries into account instead of `^`, and match for example only non whitespace chars:

```
(?<!\S)(?:\S(?!~D))*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/84Yk0b/1)

Comment: Thanks , now i know where my problem is , I used to think that the lookahead will work with the .* ,and it will asset fail in 'c' , but in fact , the  '.*' will match the whole string at first